# Check and throw exception on every function call

Tags: php, exception

I am writing a function in PHP to save an image to local file given its url. This is what I have come up with:

```
private function retrieve_image_url($image_url, $upload_path) {
    $img_data = @file_get_contents($image_url);
    if ($img_data === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Invalid image source: '. $image_url);
    }
    $file = @fopen($upload_path, "w+");
    if ($file === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Cannot open for writting: '. $upload_path);
    }
    if (fwrite($file, $img_data) === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Writing failed: '. $result);
    }
    if (fclose($file) === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Cannot close: '. $file);
    }
}
```

You can see the function is looking too complicated/hard to read as I am checking and throwing exception on every function call. Is it a bad practice to do so?

Comment: what's your exact question?

Comment: I feel that checking for exception like above is somehow too much. I have seen many code where people do not check file_get_contents, fopen, fwrite, fclose, etc failures. Is there any reason behind that? Do they have alternative ways to handle errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is ok.

Symfony have similar code for filesystem: https://github.com/symfony/Filesystem/blob/master/Filesystem.php :)

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you posted only one part of the method `retrieve_image_url`.

Lets talk about that chunk of code.

### Does it have "bad practices"?

It depends. Mostly "good practices" are hints on how your code should be, but are not mandatory.
If you follow all good practices on all your code you might be introducing over-engineering which in most cases is not needed. (And is a bad practice LOL. Take a look at [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it))

### When good practices are needed?

Good practices are needed mostly when the code is going to be part of a high level of maintenance in the future (modifications, deletions, etc). But if your code is going to be like the way is its forever and now you will bury it and forget it tomorrow, then the "good practices" might not be needed.

Also if your code is going to be shared with other people (your work colleagues, etc) is a good step to follow good practices to allow your colleagues understand the code easily and modify it easily too (if its going to be modified).

### My code is violating some good practices

On a first sight, your code inserts a little of [cyclomatic complexity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclomatic_complexity).

It is also violating the [open/closed principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle), which says you must be open for extension but not for modifications.

Why is the method private? I often do private methods when those methods are going to be called from more than one place in the class. If this method it is only being called from one place, is better to inline the method where its called.

### How can I follow good practices because my code will change a lot and I have a boss that is changing the requirements all the day and my colleagues need to understand my code and be able to change it ?

In my opinion, I would introduce your code to unit testing.
The testing will hint what is bad and what is good.
This will sound crazy, but with the time you will learn to "hear the tests what are saying to your code".

But first it needs some integration testing, A security net that will confirm that our refactorings are not breaking the code.

### Suggested Solution

First we make integration tests for all the exception cases and the valid cases:

```
public class retrieveImageUrl extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public static function casesProvider()
    {
        return array(
            array("bad URL", "Bad Upload PATH"), //Keep adding all the invalid cases here
            array("replace here with good URL", "Bad upload PATH"), //etc etc
        );
    }
    /**
     * @expectedException ImageRetrieverException
     * @dataProvider casesProvider
    */
    public function testRetrieveImageThrowsInvalidImageSource($url, $path) {
          $yourClass = new YourClass();
          $yourClass->retrieve_image_url($url, $path);
    }


    public function testRetrieveImageValidCase() {
          $yourClass = new YourClass();
          $yourClass->retrieve_image_url("replace with good url", "replace with good path");
    }
}
```

The tests will fail because the method is private.
We make the method public (that way we are able to test it)

```
public function retrieve_image_url($image_url, $upload_path) {
    $img_data = @file_get_contents($image_url);
    if ($img_data === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Invalid image source: '. $image_url);
    }
    $file = @fopen($upload_path, "w+");
    if ($file === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Cannot open for writting: '. $upload_path);
    }
    if (fwrite($file, $img_data) === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Writing failed: '. $result);
    }
    if (fclose($file) === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Cannot close: '. $file);
    }
}
```

Then we follow the open/closed principle using a composite pattern.

We create a class "Validator" which will validate two constraints in your actual code.

```
class imageValidator implements InterfaceValidator {
    private $validators;

    public __construct(array $validators = array()) {
        $this->validators = $validators;
    }

    public function validate($file = null, $imgData = null) {
        foreach($this->validators as $validator) 
            $validator->validate($file, $imgData);
    }
}
```

We create the interface that will be the implementation for all the validators.

```
interface imageInterfaceValidator {
    public function validate($file = null, $imgData = null);
}
```

The next thing is to view the constraints that validate input of the method:

`$img_data === false -> throw new ImageRetrieverException('Invalid image source: '. $image_url);`

`$file === false -> throw new ImageRetrieverException('Cannot open for writting: '. $upload_path);`

And put each in classes that implement the validator interface. For example the first validator would be:

```
class validatorImageFalse implements imageInterfaceValidator {
    public function validate($file = null, $imgData = null) {
        if($img_data === false) {
            throw new ImageRetrieverException('Invalid image source: '. $image_url);
        }
    }
}
```

And so on, with the other constraints.

When you finish your code should look like this more or less:

```
public function retrieve_image_url($image_url, $upload_path) {
    $validatorComposite = new imageValidator(array(/** Put here all the validators classes **/));
    $img_data = @file_get_contents($image_url);
    $file = @fopen($upload_path, "w+");
    $validatorComposite->validate($file, $imgData);

    if (fwrite($file, $img_data) === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Writing failed: '. $result);
    }
    if (fclose($file) === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Cannot close: '. $file);
    }
}
```

That would be, in my opinion, a way to increase maintainability. Because what if, if in the future you need to add a regular expression check in the image url, for example. You only have to add another validator.

The next thing is to apply [inversion of control](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control)

```
public function retrieve_image_url($image_url, $upload_path, imageInterfaceValidator $validatorComposite) {
    $img_data = @file_get_contents($image_url);
    $file = @fopen($upload_path, "w+");
    $validatorComposite->validate($file, $imgData);

    if (fwrite($file, $img_data) === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Writing failed: '. $result);
    }
    if (fclose($file) === false) {
      throw new ImageRetrieverException('Cannot close: '. $file);
    }
}
```

And thats it. You will see that the integration tests keep passing and that is super good.

Comment: Thank you for a quick and interesting answer. This function retrieve_image_url is actually a method of a class that will be called from other methods in the class. I think there is no problem with making it private. I see here you are using validators and you are hiding some logic in validators (write data to file, close file). To me, validators should not actually do anything other than validating data. I do not think this is a good solution in this situation for now.

Comment: Correct. There are two validators that are hiding logic. Those should not be in the validators as the responsibility should be only to validate not to do file management.